# Handling multiple states in a C++ class

Tags: c++

What would be the most efficient and modern way of handling states in C++ class?
At the moment I am using multiple bools, but the more I states I add the harder is to maintain. For example if I have a class called VideoPlayer and it has four bools defining different states. If we add set methods for each bool we need to unset all the other bools.

```
class VideoPlayer
{

public:
    void play()
    {
        play_ = true;
        pause_ = false;
        stop_ = false;
        reset_ = false;
    }

    void stop()
    {
        stop_ = true;
        play_ = false;
        pause_ = false;
        reset_ = false;
    }

private:
    bool play_;
    bool pause_;
    bool stop_;
    bool reset_;
};
```

Comment: Perhaps a small finite state machine would be appropriate.

Comment: Looks like an enum might do the job here.

Comment: If you're using C++11 then use `enum class` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your design suffers from it being easy to be in a bad state (e.g. what if both `stop_` and `play_` are both `true`?

You should use an `enum` to define a [set of finite-states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) of which only 1 can be active at any given point in time.

C++'s `enum` types are somewhat different from Swift, Java and C#'s `enum`: they're unscoped and are more permissive with implicit conversions - behaving somewhat similarly to `#define`.

C++11 adds `enum class` which is very similar to C#'s `enum`. There is no built-in functionality similar to the flexibility of Java or Swift's `enum`s, however.

You will want something like this:

```
enum class PlayerState {
    Stopped,
    Playing,
    Paused
}
```

If `Reset` is not a state, but a verb, then it should not be in the `enum` definition.

```
class VideoPlayer {
private:
    PlayerState state;
public:
    VideoPlayer() :
        state( PlayerState::Stopped )
    {

    }

    void play() {

        switch( this->state ) {
            case PlayerState::Stopped:
                 // start video here, only change `state` when complete.
                // you might want to add a "BeginPlaying" (e.g. `LoadingFileFromDisk`) state value too.
                this->state = PlayerState.Playing;
                break;
            case PlayerState::Playing:
                throw VideoPlayerStateExeception("Already playing");
            case PlayerState::Paused:
                this->resume();
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to be in multiple states at the same time with this approach? As you get it naturally with bools.

Comment: @sabotage3d no, and that's intentional. Please read the linked Wikipedia article on Finite-state Machines,

Comment: I am pretty aware of FSM and HFSM. My original question is handling multiple states. I will modify my example to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would use C++17's `std::variant`. States will become types with data.

```
struct Playing {
    float time_from_start;
};

struct Paused {
    float time_from_start;
};

struct Stopped {};

struct MediaPlayer {
    std::variant<
        Playing,
        Paused,
        Stopped
    > state;

    void play() {
        state = Playing{};
    }

    void pause() {
        state.visit([&](auto&& s){
            using S = std::decay_t<decltype(s)>;

            float time = 0;

            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<S, Playing>) {
                time = s.time_from_start;
            }

            state = Paused{time};
        });
    }
};
```

One could even add some other useful states:

```
struct ABLoop {
    float a, b, time_from_a;
};
```